# Evaluate the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} x \cdot \ln(x)$

Tags: calculus, limits

I have this assignment

Evaluate the limit:

5.$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} x \cdot \ln(x)$

I don't think we are allowed to use L'Hopital, but I can't imagine how else.

Comment: If you know that $\lim \limits_{t\to -\infty}\left(te^t\right)=0$, then set $x=e^t$.

Comment: It's safe to use L'Hospital. Write it as $\frac{\ln x}{x^{-1}}$ and you have a $\infty/\infty$ limit, and the derivatives are well-behaved.

Answer (score 5):

If you set $y=\ln x$, you can rewrite it as $\lim_{x\to-\infty}ye^y=-\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{y}{e^y}$, and you probably know what that is. Of course that approach requires that you be allowed to use known limits.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $0<x<1$, then $1/x>1$. Since $0\le\ln (1+t)\le t$ if $t>1$, we get
$$0\le \frac{1}{2}\ln\frac{1}{x}=  \ln\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}=\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-1\right)\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-1$$
if $0<x<1$. Therefore
$$0\le x\ln\frac{1}{x}\le 2(\sqrt{x}-x).$$
and we know that $\ln(1/x)=-\ln x$ holds.

Answer (score 1):

Let $t=-\ln x$. Then $x=e^{-t}$, and hence $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}x\ln x=\lim_{t\to +\infty}-e^{-t}t=\lim_{t\to +\infty}\frac{-t}{e^t}=0$$