# proving that a function is uniformly continuous

Tags: calculus

I need to prove that the function $f(x)= \ln(x) \ln(1-x)$ is uniformly continuous at the set $(0,1)$.

I tried to prove it by the definition, by Lipschitz continuity, and by Cantor's theorem.

how to prove it?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** Define $f(0)=f(1)=0$. You can check that $f$ is coutinuous over $[0,1]$. Note that uniform continuity is preserved by restriction of domain.

Comment: well, I can understand where it is going.
In the test I could not calculate the limit when x goes to 1 from the right and when x goes to 0 from the left.
how can I calculate those limit? if it was classwork I would check it on wolframalpha... but impossible in the test. Thank you.

Comment: @nir You may know that $-\ln(1-x)/x\to 1$ as $x\to 0$, and
$$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln(1-x)}{x} \cdot (x\ln x).$$
[My previous answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/987265/53976) gives how to calculate $(\ln x)/x$ as $x\to 0$. The case of $\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)$ is same (and in fact, since $f(x)=f(1-x)$, the value of $\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)$ is same as the value of $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$.